# SWIFT - KVO in xcode 6 beta 6.. observeValueForKeyPath no longer called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, key-value-observing

I have been debugging my app from beta 3 to beta 6

I cannot seem to get observeValueForKeyPath to be called.. i put a breakpoint at the top of the function and nothing happens

```
self.gameScene.viewController.joystick.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "relativePosition", options: .New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if keyPath == "relativePosition" {
    // some code here 
    }
}
```

this code was working without a hitch before..  has something changed?  I can't even get this to work in a more basic app..  is there something else I need to do?

Comment: has anyone got a basic example in xcode 6 beta 6??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a property has to have the word "dynamic" in front of it to be observable now..

```
dynamic var relativePosition: CGPoint = CGPointZero
```