# No calls occurring for observeValueForKeyPath for UIProgressView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

With the help of [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/) I was adding a progress bar to my view with Swift but the observer does not get any calls of itself.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    @IBOutlet dynamic var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupBrowser()

        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)

        let website = "https://google.com"
        let site = NSURL(string: website)

        loadURLRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: site!))
    }

    func setupBrowser() {
        let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView = wkWebView

        let wkProgressView = UIProgressView(frame: view.bounds)
        progressView = wkProgressView

        self.view.insertSubview(wkWebView, belowSubview: wkProgressView)
    }

    func loadURLRequest(request: NSURLRequest) {
        webView?.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigating")
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        print(1)
        if (keyPath == "estimatedProgress") {
            // TODO
        }
    }

}
```

Taking a look on [SWIFT - KVO in xcode 6 beta 6.. observeValueForKeyPath no longer called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378034/swift-kvo-in-xcode-6-beta-6-observevalueforkeypath-no-longer-called) or [observeValueForKeyPath not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728638/observevalueforkeypath-not-being-called) didn't help. Is UIProgressView not observable? The console shows after every page load `Finished navigating` but not once `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
 self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)
```

You observe the webview `estimateProgress`,get the progress,then set the progress of the progressView